# Commerce Kickstart: How Do I Modify The Order Receipt Page To Add Order Date?

Tags: commerce

The receipt page that displays when one completes an order (or reviews in History) contains no order date (surprising).

Where is the code that renders that page and how does one modify it to display the order date field?

```
http://example.com/user/1/orders/6
```